# CIFS not auto mounting after reboot

Tags: mount, automount, cifs

I have a 16.04 server that uses a cifs mount.  The share is confiugred in fstab.  However, it dosen't automatically mount after a restart.  To mount, I have to sudo su and the mount -a as the root user and all works fine.  Note sudo mount -a does not work either.  I am obviously missing something here?